# how to get alert message content when page load and auto click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

i have sevrale pages that have multiple jquery datatable and i just want to auto click alert when alert have this message : `'DataTables warning: table id='`. i have set this javascript for auto click if this message comes.

code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        debugger;
        var htmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)
        var indexOfAlertBeginning = "";
        var indexOfAlertEnd = "";
        var stringFromAlert = "";
        var alertMessages = "";
        if (htmlString.includes('alert(')) {
            indexOfAlertBeginning = htmlstring.indexof('alert(');
            stringFromAlert = htmlstring.substr(indexOfAlertBeginning);
            indexOfAlertEnd = stringFromAlert.indexof(')');
            alertMessages = stringFromAlert(0, indexOfAlertEnd);
        }
        if (stringFromAlert.includes('DataTables warning: table id=', 0)) {
            window.alert = function () {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

but this have no effect and alert message comes up every time. whats' wrong here please help me...

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading data to the table using ajax most of the time cause the problem unmatched column name between json data and columnname in your script.
I found this post pretty useful for datatable and .Net [Jquery Datatable with .Net](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching)

Comment: i just load data with code behind with linqtosql classes. i just only disable alert message thrown from jquery datatable.

Comment: your article is great. but i just want full source code from this. i can't found some method.